# get indexes from a list on python

Tags: python, list, min

I need to get all the indexes from the smallest elements of this list :

```
A = [5,2,1,5,6,1,7,9,2]


minimo = min(A)
#print minimo
indexArray = []
for elem in A:
    #print elem
    if elem == minimo:
        indexArray.append(A.index(elem))
print indexArray
```

need this output : [2,5] 
but it prints : [2,2]

Comment: In the case of the duplicate, just check for `== min(A)`.

Comment: `index` only gives you the first occurrence.

Comment: **index** is a function that returns the **_first_** index of an element inside a sequence and that is why the elements in the resulting list are the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `list-comprehension` with `enumerate()`. With thanks to `@MikeScotty`, a performance improvement would be to calculate the smallest value first.

Here's the code:

```
mn = min(A)
[i for i,e in enumerate(A) if e == mn]
```

which gives:

```
[2, 5]
```

which are the indexes of the `1s` in `A` - not `[2, 8]`

---

To prove this is faster, here's the `minx` `wrapper`:

```
>>> def minx(l):
...     print("called")
...     return min(l)
... 
>>> [i for i,e in enumerate(A) if e == minx(A)]
called
called
called
called
called
called
called
called
called
[2, 5]
```

---

And some timings using `timeit`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[i for i,e in enumerate(A) if e == min(A)]", globals=locals())
5.9568054789997404
>>> timeit.timeit("[i for i,e in enumerate(A) if e == 1]", globals=locals())
1.397674421001284
```

Comment: This will call ``min`` for each element, which can eat some performance with huge list. better get the smallest element outside of the list-comprehension, even if it means to have 2 lines instead of 1

Comment: @MikeScotty I will update the answer, but it would be interesting to see if `Python` *really* re-evaluates it. I'm not sure and can't find the answer through google, does it really?

Comment: Yes, you can test it if you build your own ``minX(L)`` method as wrapper for ``min()`` and print out if it gets called - you will see it gets called for each iteration.

Comment: you can use `%timeit` to check the execution time, is using ipython or notebooks.

Comment: @bhansa Good suggestion, updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
A = [5,2,1,5,6,1,7,9,2]
minimum = min(A)
res = list(filter(lambda m: A[m]==minimum, range(len(A))))
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
[2, 5]
```

Comment: A solid justification for implementing list comprehensions into the language :)

Comment: @roganjosh I agree that list comprehension is more readable than using `filter`. I just presented it as an alternative way, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

because when you use

```
A.index(elem)
```

it's equal with A.index(1) and the index of 1 will always be 2. You can try this script:

```
A=[5,2,1,5,6,1,7,9,2]
minimo = min(A)
indexArray = []
for index,value in enumerate(A):
    if value == minimo:
        indexArray.append(index)
print(indexArray)
```